# Changing the root user of MySQL

Tags: mysql, root

How do I change my root user to any other local user on mysql db?Since I have installed Ubuntu all the work is done by this superuser root now just don't want root to do all stuff of mysql...

Comment: Do you want to allow access on your mysql db to user from any remote system?

Comment: Please tag `mysql` also. It is confusing otherwise.

Comment: Is your issue solved ?

Comment: You should make your question more clear and easier to understand, see as well [how to ask a good question](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do **not** need to change the root user.

For purpose of data operations we usually **create a new mysql user** and grant certain  privileges to this user (generally limited to a database).

This can be done in following ways:

1. **From terminal**

`mysql -u root -p`

and enter the root password. Then, in the terminal you will see as `mysql>` indicating you are logged in as root in mysql.

Now you can create/modify users. For creating users,

`CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

then you can grant some prvileges to this new user by,

`GRANT ALL ON database_name.table_name TO 'username'@'localhost';`

and you can check privileges by `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost';`

This is a very general description and refer to the manual here for details. [MySQL man page for creating/modifying user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html)

2. **phpmyadmin**

This is a browser based tool which allows for doing all the user-management and database management job in one place.

After installation and configuration of this tool, phpmyadmin can be accessed in the local computer as  `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` . After login (as root or as  a specific user), management operations can be performed.

Please refer to other links about installation and usage.

Official page [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)

Comment: @Deepak - Accept the answer if problem solved. This also closes the question.